# Open a datalist with a button

Tags: javascript, dom-events, html-datalist

I have an input associated with a datalist and I want to use a button to write in the input, but I can't reproduce the event which open the list. 
The datalist is filtered but I have to click on the input to open the list...
`click()` and `focus()` don't work, any ideas?

Look at the snippet, when I click on the button 'A', the datalist doesn't open.

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('ice-cream-flavors').click();
  document.getElementById('ice-cream-choice').value += 'A';
}
```

```html
<label for="ice-cream-choice">Choose a flavor:</label>
<input list="ice-cream-flavors" id="ice-cream-choice" name="ice-cream-choice" />

<datalist id="ice-cream-flavors">
    <option value="Chocolate">
    <option value="Coconut">
    <option value="Mint">
    <option value="Strawberry">
    <option value="Vanilla">
</datalist>

<button onclick='myFunction()'>A</button>
```

Comment: Today's browsers are growing to become more secure and reliable. Allowing people to change the fundamentals of the behaviour for HTML tags via Javascript functions is extremely insecure. That's because normally, to obtain what you want you would have to create a custom dispatchEvent to handle your custom behaviour. That can easily introduce vulnerabilities thus compromising the safety of your users.

Answer (score -1):

Datalist is not supported by all browsers and it is not handled the same way. I recommend you switch to something such as flexselect: https://rmm5t.github.io/jquery-flexselect/

This might not give you the answer you wanted, but there's no solution that will work for datalist (on all browsers). You can hack your way around and make it work on Chrome or Firefox, but even that will be hard to do because Google and Mozilla have completely restricted the usage of untrusted events/triggers . Read about this here: https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5718803933560832 https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6461137440735232

Also initMouseEvent is deprecated, so are all other low-level methods that would have allowed you to create this behaviour in the past

I gave this answer to another similar question just a few moments ago: [How to show datalist with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104253/how-to-show-datalist-with-javascript)