# Simulate click with javascript does not work on input with datalist

Tags: javascript, click, html-datalist

When clicking the input field brings a dropdown like list. When trying to do the same with javascript `click()` it does not work. Why not? Can it be fixed?

```js
document.querySelector('.button-click').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Event');
  document.querySelector('#my_list').click();
});

document.querySelector('.button-focus').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Event');
  document.querySelector('#my_list').focus();
});
```

```html
<button class="button-click">Button to simulate click</button><br>
<button class="button-focus">Button to simulate focus</button><br>

<input list="list" id="my_list">
<datalist id="list">
  <option value="option1"></option>
  <option value="option2"></option>
 </datalist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) is not the correct method here. Use [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) instead and it works just fine. `focus()` mimics the behaviour of actually clicking inside the `<input/>` while `click()` only clicks onto the element.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('Event');
  document.querySelector('#my_list').focus(); // <-- change this method
});
```

```html
<button>Button</button>

<input list="list" id="my_list">
<datalist id="list">
  <option value="option1"></option>
  <option value="option2"></option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: That set the focus on the input, but what I really want is the action from the input click which in this case is to bring the dropdown with the suggestions from the datalist.

Comment: Why do you want to explicitly do this with `click()`. It's a lot easier with the method that was made for that use case.

Comment: I don't really care about the method name I'm using. All I want is to trigger the dropdown with the options. Focus don't do that.

Comment: The longer I think about it, the more it looks like an XY-problem to me. I'm almost certain using focus is the way to go here and I still don't see any reason why it shouldn't be used. If you really want to use click (and make things twice as complicated), I recommend reading this post on [How to show datalists with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60104253/how-to-show-datalist-with-javascript).

Comment: Alright. It seems not to be possible. I'll probably need to go with the next best thing which is :focus. At least I can show the user where to go with that hint. Thanks!